# PHPMailer error sending mail with smtp.gmail.com

Tags: php, email

After going through all the steps of phpmailer and looking around stackoverflow.
Tested all the answers I could find from people that had the same problems as I do, but it doesn't work for me.

```
My code is simple:

<?php
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'I entered a valid gmail';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'I entered my password(I'm not giving it to you people, I know what you can do ;) )';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; 
$mail->Mailer = "smtp"; 
$mail->From = 'The email its sent from';
$mail->FromName = 'Lobby desk';
$mail->addAddress(' Recipients mail ');               // Name is optional

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}

?>
```

I hope someone can point me to what is wrong with my code and why it gives the error:

> SMTP connect() failed

And:

> SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14  Please log in via
>   your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again

I have entered the correct password for the gmail account and edited my settings to allow less secure apps.

**As always, much thanks in advance to the users that take me seriously.**

Comment: 'I entered a valid gmail';  remove these kind of comments and put some dummy id and password. Example like abc@gmail.com  and password = "******"; etc @CasualVictim

Answer (score 2):

Please check once in your gmail account settings for permission to use this account to use as mailer. I think that may be the issue.

Comment: Where do I do that in gmail? I have looked for it, but cannot find it

Answer (score 0):

problem in this line

```
$mail->Password = 'I entered my password(I'm not giving it to you people, I know what you can do ;) )';  
                  ^                      ^^^                                                          ^
```

change to

```
$mail->Password = "I entered my password(I'm not giving it to you people, I know what you can do ;) )";
```

[Basic Example using Gmail with PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebgmail)

Comment: I have changed the single quotes to doubles, but it still gives me the same error as before.

Comment: check that link as well. its show how to use php mailer